# How to make dynamic dropdown in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm working on a e-commerce project where there will be radio buttons for size selection. I have a dropdown for quantity. I want to make this dropdown dynamic based on stock available for the user selected size. Can anyone tell me how this can be done on Rails? without cluttering my view file with lot of javascript!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 with prototype (default afaik), you could use the prototype legacy helpers ([Link on Github](https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper)) to add an observer and render a partial view for your dropdown box. You could add an observer like this

```
<%= observe_field 'element_var_name',
      :url => { :action => "another_action_here" },
      :update => "div_tag_to_update",
      :with => "'selected='+ escape($('element_var_name').value)" %>
```

Be sure to adjust `element_var_name` and the action to your situation. `div_tag_to_update` is the div that will update with the dropdown box. The `another_action_here` action should render a view like this:

```
def call_ids_by_type
  @element_list = ... # whatever fits for you, like: [[key, value],[key, value]]
  render :layout => false
end
```

In the partial view, you can use the element list to generate the dropdown box:

```
<%= f.select :var_name, @element_list %>
```