# Rails 3 with Prototype Making Dynamic Drop Downs inside a form with database calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been searching for a good way to create dynamic dropdowns that are part of a form.  The dropdowns need to be populated with data from the database based on the previous dropdown.  I have not found a good rails 3/prototype solution.  I have seen some partial solutions with [jQuery](http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/) and using [prototype legacy helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590561/how-to-make-dynamic-dropdown-in-rails).  However, I read it is not a good idea to use the legacy helpers so I am trying to do it without them while still using prototype.

I understand this is a large question however, I assume this has already been done several times and if somebody has a good how to it would be much appreciated.  If not my plan of attack is use onchange to trigger a javascript call to send a request to the server.  Then update the partial, the next select box, with the apropriate options and then repeat.

Immediate Question: How do you generate a ajax page call using prototype?  I need to send the result of the first drop down to my controller.  The url would be car_infos/update_make/"year".

I have this select tag in my larger form that calls a javascript function.

```
    <%= select_tag 'year', options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicle_years, "year", "year"), {:include_blank => true, :onchange => "submitYear(this.value)" }%>
```

Thanks for any help as I get started with Rails.

**Update:**  I am generating a request to the server with this javascript:

```
  function submitYear(year){
    new Ajax.Request('/udpate_make/'+year, {method: 'get'});
}
```

However, it doesn't generate the correct url.  If I put /car_infos/update_make it generates car_infos/car_infos/udpate_make/.  If I take at the /car_infos part it just does /update_make and leaves off the car_infos.  I get two or none.  Still not sure how to generate the proper url of 'car_infos/update_make/year'  I will implement the observe option as mentioned by @Jaryl but still having problems with the url generation.  Here is my routes...

```
resources :car_infos

match 'car_infos/update_make/:year', :controller => 'car_infos', :action => 'update_make'
```

**Update**: with another part of the journey

To solve the duplicate part of the url I had to do the following:

```
    function submitYear(year){
    new Ajax.Request('update_make/'+year, {method: 'get'});
}
```

Notice the missing / from the previous example.  Still don't know why when putting car_infos in there it duplicates it. but at least I am generating a valid Ajax request to the server now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to create my dynamic drop downs with Protoype in case anybody else is going down this path.  Please let me know if there is a better way:

Create Routes for appropriate controller, my controller is car_infos

```
    match 'car_infos/update_make/:year', :controller => 'car_infos', :action => 'update_make'
match 'car_infos/update_model/:year/:make', :controller => 'car_infos', :action => 'update_model'
```

Inside form have first dropdown built and render a partial.

```
    <div id="year_sel">
    <%= f.label :car_year %>
    <%= select_tag 'year', options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicle_years, "year", "year"), {:include_blank => true, :onchange => "submitYear(this.value)" }%>
  </div>
  <div id="make_select">
    <%= render 'make_sel' %>
  </div>
```

Build the link in javascript in your application.js file:

```
    function submitYear(year){
    new Ajax.Request('update_make/'+year, { method: 'get'});
}
```

Have your .js.rjs file that responds to the ajax request and renders the partial.

```
page.replace_html('make_select', render('make_sel'))
```

In your controller function make sure it responds to the .js format.

Hope this helps somebody else since it took me two days to find all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Rails 3, where legacy helpers are deprecated. You should use something like [jQuery UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs). What you do is take out the JS helper codes from your select tag like so:

```
<%= select_tag 'year', options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicle_years, "year", "year") %>
```

Then in your JS file (I'm using jQuery here), you add codes that performs the JS function:

```
$('#year').change(function(e) {
  // some AJAX call here using $('#year').val()
});
```

To do this in Prototype (see [docs for observing events](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe)), it will be something like this:

```
Event.observe('#year', 'change', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: is it a good idea to mix jQuery and Prototype?  I have an app that is almost built with Prototype.  I am not sure how much adjusting I will need to do if I switch over to jQuery now, that is why I am looking for a prototype solution.

Comment: You could translate it to Prototype, oh well, I'll try point you in the write direction. Wait for the edit.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to observe that will help. But still having issue generating the correct url for my controller.  See edit above.

Comment: Did you mean to look for update_make in root: new Ajax.Request('/update_make/'+year, {method: 'get'});